# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'some' in owlready libraries

Tags: python, owl, owlready

I'm trying to create a class called pizza in the ontology of pizza_onto with the owlready library. but I get the following error. what would be the reason?

Owlready Code: (pizza.py)

```
from owlready2 import *
onto_path.append("C:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/izmir/pizza_onto.owl")
onto = get_ontology("C:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/izmir/pizza_onto.owl")
onto.load()

with onto:
    class NonVegetarianPizza(onto.Pizza):
        equivalent_to = [
            onto.Pizza
            & ( onto.has_topping.some(onto.MeatTopping)
            | onto.has_topping.some(onto.FishTopping)
            ) ]
        def eat(self): print("Beurk! I'm vegetarian!")
```

Error:

```
* Owlready2 * Warning: optimized Cython parser module 'owlready2_optimized' is not available, defaulting to slower Python implementation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/izmir/pizza.py", line 7, in <module>
    class NonVegetarianPizza(onto.Pizza):
  File "c:/Users/BAUM-PC/Desktop/izmir/pizza.py", line 10, in NonVegetarianPizza
    & ( onto.has_topping.some(onto.MeatTopping)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'some'
```

Comment: You need to trace the attributes of `onto`: it appears that `has_topping` is `None` is some case, which makes `.some` an invalid reference.  Perhaps you need to guard that access by using `getattr` with a default value or safety clause?

Comment: getattr () is used with a maximum of 3 arguments. `onto.has_topping.some (onto.FishTopping)`,
How do I use it with `getattr ()` ?

Comment: i guess this usage is getting wrong. `getattr(onto, 'has_topping', 'some', 'onto', 'FishTopping')`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "python getattr tutorial examples", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: I already did the necessary google search. but as I said, I couldn't find a `getattr()` usage with 4 arguments. my code consist of 4 arguments.

Comment: does the property `has_topping` exist in your ontology?

Comment: no. `has_topping` not exist in my ontology. I'm trying to create ontology with the owlready library on python

Comment: There is no `getattr` implementation with an arbitrary quantity of qualifying arguments.  You cannot force it to use the syntax you want.  You have to adjust your usage to what `getattr` does for you.  Again, read the documentation to see how it works, and alter your code to match.